# Google Analytics Tracking GA.js vs Analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics.js

I'm trying to use this code to track an event in Google Analytics

```
    _trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

This seems to be meant to be use with the GA.js Analytics "package", however I'm using the Analytics.js

Like this

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), 
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Is there a way I can do even tracking with this code only ?
Or do I have to use

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google    -analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Do I need both of these codes?
Or is there some different way using only Analytics.js

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: 
Indeed I probably didn't explain what I want, it might not even possible. 
I want to work with Funnels on Events, and I want to use _trackEvent (that's what I thought it would do) to mark a user as having Entered the Funnel, if the event is send then we will have the normal funnel. 
So if 10 users enter the page and 1 clicks on the button, I would have 10 events on the Funnel with 1 success

Answer (score 6):

analytics.js will report to GA same as the old code, but it has different syntax, so you can't use `_trackEvent`.

Here is a link to the [basic on-page syntax with analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), and here is a link for [event tracking with analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');      // GA account ID goes here
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',           // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'category',  // Required.
  'eventAction': 'action',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'opt_label',
  'eventValue': opt_value,
  'nonInteraction': opt_noninteraction
});
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I believe that code is to send the event itself, which I already have. What I need is to "initiate" the event, so if the event doesn't get triggered I get 0 / 1 events (one started but not completed). Which is what _trackEvent does I believe

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "initiate" the event.  There is no "initiation" of events in GA. `_trackEvent` doesn't "initiate" an event in the traditional code; it sends the event, same as analytics.js.  IOW it is a "trigger" command. GA events are not like other variables like custom fields where you set them and then something else triggers the request.  They *are* triggers, because they are events that happen.

Comment: Now, you can wrap the GA event code in your own condition or wrapper function that is called if some condition is met (e.g. - successful form completion, onclick of a link, etc.) but once the GA event code is called, it will always send a request to GA because it is a "trigger" command, like a pageView.

Comment: Indeed I probably didn't explain what I want, it might not even possible. I want to work with Funnels on Events, and I want to use _trackEvent (that's what I thought it would do) to mark a user as having Entered the Funnel, if the event is send then we will have the normal funnel. So if 10 users enter the page and 1 clicks on the button, I would have 10 events on the Funnel with 1 success

Comment: okay, so it sounds like you should just have normal page view tracking for when a visitor goes to the page, and then trigger the event when the visitor clicks the button.  Then in your reports you'd look at the page as the dimension, and the number of page views and the event as the metrics. Alternatively you could have 2 events: one for page view and one for clicking the button.

Comment: @CrayonViolent is correct that the behavior is the same between the two syntaxes -- see the comparison at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#events